# Is this the correct way to select with updlock and then conditionally insert?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, deadlock

I have a table which tracks 'reservations', defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reservation]
(
    [OrderId] nvarchar(40) CONSTRAINT [PK_Reservation_OrderId] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [GroupId] nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
    [Currency] nvarchar(40) NOT NULL,
    [Quantity] decimal(19,10) NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Reservation_GroupId_Currency]
ON [dbo].[Reservation]
(
    [GroupId],
    [Currency]
)
INCLUDE (
    [Quantity],
    [OrderId]
)
```

As the application receives an order, it first checks if the sum total of reservations belonging to the relevant GroupId/Currency pair is below some fixed amount.  If it is, it then inserts a row to represent that this new order has been accepted.

The query for this is as follows (with the params coming from the application):

```
declare @total decimal(19, 10);

select @total = sum(Quantity)
from [orders].[Reservation] with(updlock)
where [GroupId] = @groupId
and [Currency] = @currency

set @total = coalesce(@total, 0)

if (@total + @quantityToReserve) <= @someDefinedLimit
    insert into [orders].[Reservation] ([GroupId], [Currency], [Quantity], [OrderId])
    values (@groupId, @currency, @quantityToReserve, @orderId)
```

The general idea being to prevent 2 concurrent processes both doing the `select` part of the query, both deciding they're allowed to insert, and both inserting.  My understanding is that the `updlock` should block the 2nd process from performing the select for the same GroupId/Currency combination.

This query is being performed in a transaction at an isolation level of `read committed`

It seems to work correctly (no unwanted extra insertions), but I do experience periodic deadlocks.  From reading around, it seems that this is likely due to the nonclustered index keyed on GroupId/Currency.  I don't fully understand the internals, but something along the lines of:

- Process 1: Gets U lock on nonclustered index
- Process 1: Gets X lock on clustered index
- Process 1: Releases U lock on nonclustered index
- Process 2: Gets U lock on nonclustered index
- Process 2: Tries to get X lock on clustered index, blocked by Process 1
- Process 3: Tries to get U lock on nonclustered index, blocked by Process 2

(Again, I don't claim to fully understand the internals, or if the above sequence is correct.  I got this from reading an answer from a MS staff member here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/28f7bb6e-faf0-4587-bf34-63c3344a23f8/use-of-the-quotupdlockquot-hint-with-update-and-insert-statements?forum=transactsql)

Is there a fundamentally different approach I should be taking to the problem of "do insert only if the results of a previous query in the same transaction say so"?

Are intermittent deadlocks unavoidable in this kind of situation, or are they just a symptom of the way I've designed the indexes and/or the query?

**Edit: updated with deadlock graph and query plan**

Column names are slightly different to the initial question, but the logic is the same.  `PortfolioId` = `GroupId`, `Currency` = `Asset`

Deadlock XML: https://pastebin.com/YPeA7xbU
[image: Deadlock graph]

Query plan:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1RP6Vd9c

[image: Query plan]

Comment: Given the above indexes, and the whole batch running inside a transaction, I don't see how a deadlock could happen, as the locks are always happening in the same order. A `holdlock, updlock` hint might help. Are there other queries accessing the table? Please show us a full deadlock graph XDL, and please share the query plan via https://pastetheplan.com

Comment: Side note: you could combine the whole batch into one statement: `insert into [orders].[Reservation] ([GroupId], [Currency], [Quantity], [OrderId]) select @groupId, @currency, @quantityToReserve, @orderId where (select isnull(sum(Quantity), 0)
from [orders].[Reservation] with(updlock) where [GroupId] = @groupId and [Currency] = @currency) + @quantityToReserve <= @someDefinedLimit;` although that is unlikely to solve the deadlock

Comment: @Charlieface I read that adding `holdlock` basically raises the transaction isolation level to `serializable` and can still incur deadlocks.  But regarding why they're happening in the first place, I also don't understand, given the consistent ordering of the statements.  This is why I think it's something to do with the order in which it takes various locks on the nonclustered index, I'm just not sure what exactly.

Comment: `holdlock` might help in instances when there are no rows to read at all in the `select`, it can indeed end up locking too much, but given the indexes it's unlikely to cause more deadlocks. Like I said, we need the deadlock graph, and the query plan, it's impossible to diagnose otherwise.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to get the deadlock graph.  Azure sql does make them available via its event logging, but annoyingly it seems to also truncate the XML after a certain length.  I'll have to work on getting the full one.

Comment: @Charlieface Updated with the deadlock graph and query plan

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry, added the relevant links.  And no, this code only runs once per transaction.

Comment: HOLDLOCK will cause the entire range to lock (so will cover yet to be inserted records), but if the specified range doesn't exist, could expand to include the next closest matches (so the groups on either side).  You might try including an XLOCK hint as well as HOLDLOCK to promote immediately to an X instead  (so WITH (ROWLOCK, HOLDLOCk, XLOCK)) and see if that resolves the deadlock issues.  If that doesn't resolve it then maybe a lock tracking table so each transaction can explicitly reserve a "I'm updating a group".

Comment: There are actually three processes involved in this deadlock. I don't get how this is possible, why are the different processes holding multiple locks in the first place, when only a single `PortfolioId, Asset` pair is actually being accessed per process? Moreover, two of the locks appear to have the same lock ID `lock229b46d1d80` and resource ID `KEY: 5:72057594083803136 (507b6f11b1e7)`, again I don't understand how that's possible. Perhaps @PaulWhite will chime in on it at some point.

Comment: Instead of using Table Hints to try and avoid deadlocking, you may want to look into explicit mutex/semaphore locking via [`sp_getapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [`sp_releaseapplock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-releaseapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).  This approach will allow you to programmatically lock your transactions without deadlocking one another, though it will require additional coding.

Comment: It's likely that the index is not even being used here, because you have `nvarchar(4000)`. I'm guessing the client app is not setting the correct length for the parameters, such as by just using `AddWithValue`. Always set the parameter types and lengths explicitly.